# Why the "v" in mkfs.vfat?

Tags: command-line

I read in an Internet article to format a partition to FAT32 with the following command:

`sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdXn`

Now I read the man page for `mkfs.vfat` and it shows `mkfs.fat` as the name of the command without the `v`. After that I tried formatting a partition without the `v` and expectedly it worked. Why is there a synonymous command called `mkfs.vfat` instead of just `mkfs.fat`?

Edit: Oh, and in `man mkfs` `mkfs.vfat` is listed instead of `mkfs.fat` in "SEE ALSO".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#VFAT - this has nothing to do with Unix or Linux.

Comment: vfat filesystem are used in linux world (for instance, I create vfat floppy image to transmit information/files to a system with no network and ILO/ILOM interface, or tu use kickstart file for redhat installation).

Comment: @Archemar: Uh, from the Wiki article above it seems VFAT is a Microsoft invention and Linux only supports it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928982/what-is-the-difference-between-vfat-and-fat32-file-systems

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) is a family of filesystems, comprising at least, in chronological order:

- [FAT12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT12), a filesystem used on floppies since the late 1980s, in particular by MS-DOS;
- [FAT16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT16), a small modification of FAT12 supporting larger media, introduced to support hard disks;
- [vFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#VFAT), which is backward compatible with FAT, but allows files to have longer names which only vFAT-aware applications running on vFAT-aware operating systems can see;
- [FAT32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32), another modification of FAT16 designed to support larger disk sizes. In practice FAT32 is almost always used with vFAT long file name support, but technically 16/32 and long-file-names-yes/no are independent.

Because those filesystems are very similar, they're usually handled by the same drivers and tools. `mkfs.vfat` and `mkfs.fat` are the same tool; an empty FAT16 filesystem and an empty vFAT filesystem look exactly the same, so `mkfs` doesn't need to distinguish between them. (You can think of FAT16 and vFAT as two different ways of seeing the same filesystem rather than two separate filesystem formats.)

Comment: Did I understand it right that in vFAT additional hidden files are added and the filenames are concatenated for the longer filenames?

Comment: @mkdrive2 Yes (well, more precisely, these are hidden directory entries that FAT16-only systems treat as unused and vFAT systems treat as giving a long file name to a file in that directory).